# Composition of projections remains the same

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider a plane $π : Ax + By + Cz + D = 0$ and a line
$d :
\frac{x − x_0}
p
=
\frac{y − y_0}
q
=
\frac{z − z_0}
r$
.
If $π \nparallel d$, show that:$p_{\pi,d}\circ p_{\pi,d} = p_{\pi,d}$. I have found the next formula but I don't know how to use is.
[image]

Comment: The identity you’re supposed to verify is often what defines a projection in the first place. All you really need to do is show that $p$ is the identity map on $\mathbf\pi$. However, if you insist on using that formula, apply it to itself and simplify.

Comment: So I can change $[M]_{R}$ to a column matrix (x,y,z) but how about that [d]?

Comment: What about it? The text that you’ve quoted says “... where $\vec d=(p,q,r)$ ...”

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use an unwieldy formula that you don’t understand, work with the definition of the projection: the projection of a point $\mathbf x$ is the intersection of the line through $\mathbf x$ parallel to $d$ with the plane $\pi$. It should be obvious the the projection of any point on $\mathbf\pi$ is the point itself, therefore $p_{\mathbf\pi,d}(p_{\mathbf\pi,d}(\mathbf x))=p_{\mathbf\pi,d}(\mathbf x)$.

If you must work with that formula that you looked up somewhere, I’d suggest packaging it up into the $4\times4$ matrix $$P = \frac1{Ap+Bq+Cr}\begin{bmatrix}Bq+Cr&-Bp&-Cp&-Dp\\-Aq&Ap+Cr&-Cq&-Dq\\-Ar&-Br&Ap+Bq&-Dr\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and then verifying that $P^2=P$.